# Translation help with の?

Tags: particle-の

I love this song ハウトゥ世界征服 by NERU feat. 鏡音リンと鏡音レン. However, there is one line I struggle with:

心の傷口を治してくれ

Wouldn't one say

傷口の心を治してくれ

Instead? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the N1のN2 construction be aware that the actual thing you’re talking about is N2. The relation between the nouns is that the second is a part (or aspect) of the first.

**examples:**

傷口の中 = in (the middle of) the wound ( you’re talking about part of the wound)

心の傷口 = the wound of the heart (you’re talking about the heart, but focusing on the wound, not the entire heart)

山田さんの仕事 = the work / job of mr Yamada (You choose to focus on that aspect of Yamada)

I hope this helped you out.

- N = noun

Answer (score 1):

When I get confused by a phrase AのB it helps to translate it using の with a meaning “of” to “B of A” (note the nouns are reverted in English).

So for  心 (heart/soul) and 傷口 (wound) then 「心の傷口」is the “wound(s) of my heart”

> 心の傷口を治してくれ
>
> Please heal the wounds of my heart

Note that Japanese doesn’t differentiate singular and plural so we just have to guess there. 心{こころ} typically means “heart” metaphorically like your “soul” rather than a literal beating organ in your body.

Everyday speech often omits “の“ to avoid repetition. I imagine song lyrics may even go further with such creative liberties to match a musical melody. For example:

> 私**の**心傷口を治してくれ
>
> Please heal the wounds of my heart
>
> 私**の**心**の**傷口を治してくれ
>
> Please heal the wounds of **my** heart

Answer (score 0):

心 = heart

傷口 = wound

心の傷口 = heart's wound

を治してくれ = heal it for me

What is unusual about the phrase as-is?